# Weird Java Import

Tags: java, import

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/rpc/soap/SOAPFaultException.html

I am trying to import

```
javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException
```

More details in the Oracle's documentaiton. As I understand, it says it is only available in the EE edition. I previously had SE, now just installed EE. However, javac still tells me it can't find getDetail() element. It can find the object since this class exists in SE, but without all the methods of the EE edition of the class. It seems I am not installing EE correctly (since when I look in the scr.zip, I can't find the right methods either). Should I uninstall SE first? Any ideas?

Comment: Check that you have your classpath configured correctly. Start by looking at your PATH environment variable.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?  You are probably invoking the `javac` from the wrong JDK.  (All these issues are a lot easier to deal with if you use an IDE, which I would recommend for Java development.)

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and I set the JRE and JDK to 1.7 (which I just downloaded). I will try re-installing.

Comment: Reinstalling doesn't make any sence. Check CLASSPATH, as [cdeszaq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20770/cdeszaq) already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add one of the jars [listed here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException) to your CLASSPATH.

Find there jars, that were installed with your J2EE SDK.

Comment: I understand that I was providing little information, so I'll just pick you as the correct answer since it was hard for anyone to really help me and you gave me the right idea. After I uninstalled all the previoud jre and jdk, installed J2EE and specifically referenced j2ee.jar in the -cp it compiled finally. Thanks for everyone's help.